# Flutter Scrolling items with animation

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-animation

In android we have this https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators to create animation when scrolling for RecyclerView.
But in Flutter I didn't find anything similar like this.
My current work around idea is that every item will create a new AnimationController, forward that controller when WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback is callback. But with that solution the animation is not as smooth as the Android example.

The gif is > 2MB so I post the link here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators/master/art/demo4.gif